# Why is 5. f5 so necessary in the Dzindzi-Indian Opening/Modern Defense: Pterodactyl, Beefeater Variation?

Tags: opening, evaluation, modern-defense

I have played a couple of games as black with this line. It is a simple plan: to put pressure on the weak c3 and c4 pawns.

This line is mainly known as the Dzindzi-Indian Opening, according to the comments and [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PHvUGZq3iuo) video. It's also called the Modern Defense: Pterodactyl, Beefeater Variation according to [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/openings/A40-Modern-Defense-Pterodactyl-Beefeater-Variation).

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 g6 2. c4 Bg7 3. Nc3 c5 4. d5 Bxc3 5. bxc3 f5
```

I have tried it while playing correspondence, so I have followed the move suggested by databases: 5. f5. This has had good results after quickly playing Qa5, trying to attack the weak pawns along with other minor pieces.

5...f5  **347**
2018    2403/2426/2709   30.3%  25.6%   44.1%

5...Qa5 **22**
2017    2359/2306/2586   50%    22.7%   27.3%

5...e5  **5**
2014    2370/2338/2418   40%       20%     40%

5...d6  **1**
2010    Steadman vs. Bosboom 0-1

*[Chesstempo database for the position](https://chesstempo.com/game-database.html)

I wonder what the reason is for taking away a tempo to play f5 while the plan is clear, at least as I play it: to profit from the doubled pawns by attacking on the queenside.

Is f5 played to avoid e4?

Comment: @Rewan Demontay No it is ok, same sense. Thank you for making my text more clear and btw giving me the oportunity of learning a bit of english wich I like to do.

Comment: I think the variation is named pterodactyl variant. Maybe it should be specified at the title.

Comment: @Rewan Demontay I would like to clarify I have followed **the move** sugested by db. I feel unfair in this cases to edit it, so please delete that s and I will do it myself too with the last comment.

Comment: @Rewan Demontay no, only after the diagram change the moves --> the move. As this is not a line very sugested on db. I do not have followed the 5 moves. I followed f5 only, while with no assistance I would have played Qa5

Comment: This line is better known as the Dzindzi-Indian Defense. You will find a lot of material under that name.

Comment: @Rewan Demontay. chess.com is a good source for the variation. It is on modern theory so that the befeeter name I guess.

Comment: @fuxia. No, at Dzindzi-indian Defense I do not see black tradding his bishop on move 4

Comment: @Rewan Demontay No I just say I have played this specific move, not the moves sugested by db so I prefer: "I have tried it while playing correspondance, so I have followed the **move** [s] sugested by databases. It is just to change a word

Comment: @Universal_learner Beefeater is the ECO name, but Dzindzi-Indian is the name this variation is called normally. It's the same thing. Here's an [Introduction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHvUGZq3iuo) explaining this. `f5` is mandatory to make e4 a bit more expensive for White (it's still a good move).

Comment: @fuxia I saw a first video where the plan is the same but BxN is not played before f5. But you are totaly rigth this is also named Dzindzi_Indian I realized after reading some posts and watching my second video

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want a White pawn getting to e5, especially with a friend at f4.  White can let you have a c-pawn if he can achieve such a central dominance.

Also, without f5 it is awkward to develop the Ng8 -- you notice none of the variations you show have Nf6.  But now after f5, Nf6 will grip the e4 square.   Thus White often plays e4 anyway!

Answer (score 4):

By playing ...f5 you're trying to weaken the e4 push. This is the most important immediate thing to attend to. It's not like White's doubled pawns are going to run away anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

f5 has the aim to stop the e4 push. However, a "refutation" of the line is 1. d4 g6 2. c4 Bg7 3. Nc3 c5 4. d5 Bxc3 5. bxc3 f5 6. e4 fxe4 7. f3!; Here, if black captures in f3, then white has a strong attack due to the better development. Therefore, in his DVD series on the Dzindzi, GM Ron Henley suggests 7. ...e5!, but he doesn't consider the first choice of Stockfish, which seems very good for white: 8. Nh3! with the idea of Nf2 (ff 8. ... exf3 then simply Qxf3).